# Different checkboxes send the user to different pages when checked

Tags: php, javascript, forms, checkbox

I need a form in which the checkboxes would open different pages based on their selection when the form is submitted.

So, say I have this simple form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="sign" />     
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="sign" />     
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="sign" />     
<input value="4" type="checkbox" name="sign" />     
<input value="5" type="checkbox" name="sign" />     
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

When an user checks value 1 and submits, he will be redirected to page A. If a user checks 1 and 4 he will be redirected to a different page (page F, for instance).  If a user checks 2, 3 and 4 he will be redirected to page R, and so on... There would be 25 different combinations, and therefore, 25 different page results for this form when an user submits it.

In other words, when the form is submitted somehow the system would read which checkboxes were checked and associate each possible combination with a different URL.

Can it be done? If so, how? Anyone ever made something similar? I've searched a long time for solutions, but found only slightly similar ones, not exactly what I need, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Switch cases or if-else statements. I would go with if-else. But there would be 25 such cases like you said. Do it using Javascript.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using radio buttons? Right now the user can select multiple choices.

Comment: He wants multiple validations too

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1692281.aspx/1

Comment: yes, i would need multiple choices, so checkboxes instead of radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="sign[1]" />     
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="sign[2]" />     
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="sign[3]" />     
<input value="4" type="checkbox" name="sign[4]" />     
<input value="5" type="checkbox" name="sign[5]" />     
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['sign'][1]))
    header("Location: a.php");
elseif(isset($_POST['sign'][2]) AND isset($_POST['sign'][3]))
    header("Location: b.php");
```

Comment: @Sean - They are the same exact thing, just two different ways of doing. It's just personal preference.

Comment: Yes, I understand they are the same... both of them work, so thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a couple of ways.  One is that you can use javascript to intercept the form submission, change the value of the form "action", and then execute the submit.

A second approach might be to just send all this data to a single script and based on the selected values perform a redirect to the intended page.

Answer (score 0):

From should look like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
<input value="4" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
<input value="5" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

And the post like:

```
if(!empty($_POST['sign'])) {
    if(in_array(1, $_POST['sign'])) {
        // if just 1, go to page
    } elseif(in_array(1, $_POST['sign']) && in_array(4, $_POST['sign'])) {
        // if 1 and 4, go to page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just consider each of the inputs as a bit. So, you will always have 5 bits to consider.

Then define an associative array of 25 entries corresponding to each of the possible values:

```
00001
00010
...

var links = {
    "00001" : "www.google.com",

];
```

Then, when you submit the form, just set the `target` attribute of the `form` based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you and I had no choice than following this idea, I would use something like that in jQuery (assuming your post vars are treated in the page you want to reach):

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input value="1" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
    <input value="2" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
    <input value="3" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
    <input value="4" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
    <input value="5" type="checkbox" name="sign[]" />     
    <input type="submit" /> 
</form>


$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    var checked_array = new Array();
    $("#myForm input").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")
            checked_array.push($(this).attr("value"));
    });

    if ( checked_array.indexOf(2) !== -1 && checked_array.indexOf(5) !== -1)
       ("#myForm").attr("action", "/url1.php") ;
    else if etc...
});
```